# How to search a specific directory recursively for specific string content within .odt .ods .doc & .xls files

Tags: search, sed, grep, find

I have Linux Mint 17.2.

I wish to be able to search a specific directory recursively, for a specific string, within any of .odt .ods .doc & .xls files. The search string may have spaces in it eg "like this or this".

I beleive .odt .ods .doc .xls document files are kept in either compressed or binary format which makes straight forward use of grep for searching content inapplicable.

The solution also needs to be able to search through file names that have spaces in them eg "this long file name.odt".

Please format as a one liner.

If you can add find so that specific file types or file names can be searched that would also be beneficial.

Thank you

ps this is perhaps not as straight forward as it might first appear. For example the solution posted [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1488252) is as follows

```
sudo apt-get install antiword
for i in *.doc; do
antiword $i | grep 185223 && echo Found in $i
done
```

However it does not cope with file names that have spaces in them.

An idea posted [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-s...r-text-string/) shows how to search file names that have spaces in them using sed though I was unable to convert this from the given piped one liner to a multi-line script, with a loop in it and a variable, as shown above.

Comment: `Please format as a one liner.`. Why on earth would you care how many lines a solution is on? You can always cram it all onto a single line later if you feel it's somehow useful to do that. The reason the solution you posted doesn't work for file names that contain spacing is because you're break a fundamental shell programming rule - always quote your variables unless you have a specific reason not to and fully understand all of the caveats.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for your current directory:

```
grep -ri --include=*.odt "like this or this" .
```

That will recursively search (-r) all odt files for the string in all files of the current directory. (.) It will be case insensitive (-i).

Answer (score 0):

The UNIX command for finding files is named (not co-incidentally) `find`:

```
find . \( -name '*.odt' -o -name '*.ods' -o -name '*.doc' -o -name '*.xls' \) -print |
while IFS= read -r file
do
    antiword "$file" | grep 185223 && echo Found in "$file"
done
```

The above will fail if your file names contain newlines - if that can happen put the `antiword...` part in a shell script and invoke it with xargs:

```
find... -print0 | xargs -0 command
```

You may want to look at grep args to handle 185223 occurring as part of a larger string or occurring multiple times in the file (exit after first match?) and having grep print the matching file name itself instead of needing an echo.

Comment: Thanks @Ed. It works apart from antiword not handling odt files. It passes back `./file name.odt is not a Word Document.` May be the solution is unoconv to html and parse that.